# Drive replacement on Intel Raid, Ubuntu errors

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid

I have a RAID 1 system with two drives. The other drive was reported as failing so I replaced it.

However, the rebuild seems not to work as expected. The Intel manager (pre-boot) marks the raid for Rebuild, but it seems not to happen. Occasionally I get I/O error from the filesystem (e.g. trying to `ls` on shell).

dmraid reports errors:

```
root:/home/user# dmraid -r
ERROR: ddf1: seeking device "/dev/dm-2" to 18446744073709421056
ERROR: hpt37x: seeking device "/dev/dm-2" to 4608
ERROR: hpt45x: seeking device "/dev/dm-2" to 18446744073709547008
ERROR: isw: seeking device "/dev/dm-2" to 18446744073708469760
ERROR: sil: seeking device "/dev/dm-2" to 18446744073709289984
/dev/sdb: isw, "isw_dhdbhbfgef", GROUP, ok, 1953525166 sectors, data@     0
/dev/sda: isw, "isw_dhdbhbfgef", GROUP, ok, 1953525166 sectors, data@ 0
```

How can I fix this?

Edit: Or help me to understand what happens here, I'm all new to Raid.

Edit2: Learning more about the problem. It seems that rebuilding is started automatically byt the OS, but at the time of the IO error the rebulding hangs. I do not know which one happens first, the handing rebuild or the I/O error and which one is cause fot the problem.

Any insight what could cause iws to hang/or cause the I/O error? Could it simply be a HW issue in the disk? It is reported otherwise healthy but has few bad sectors.

Comment: I think you want to read [the answer to *ZFS endless resilvering*](http://serverfault.com/a/523413/58408) on [sf]. I can't tell for absolutely certain, but I'm pretty sure that it explains what's going on in your situation.

Comment: Thanks Michael, but propably not this issue as I have only 2 drives.

Comment: Actually, unless I'm missing something in your description, it might be *exactly* your problem. The problem occurs when the RAID array drops to its redundancy threshold (no available redundancy) and there are latent errors. At that point there is no good way to recover. Different RAID systems handle this in different ways, but no way is a good way of handling it because no matter what you do at that point, there is data loss.

Comment: I undestood that in the aswer you linked to there was one disk worth of redundancy and then of course 2 disks failing means data loss. However, I have 2 disk and lost one. There can be latent errors, though, and then I agree, data is lost.

Comment: Exactly; failure doesn't have to mean full, outright, "stops responding to anything" failure. Failure can also mean partial failure, like a small number of sectors going bad. Since plain RAID has no understanding of the *meaning* of the data stored there (ZFS does know what type of data is stored; pool metadata, file system metadata, user data have different criticality for the system) the least bad course of action in such a situation is often to abort and tell the administrator to restore from backup onto a reconstructed array. But this is speculation.